# Adding Channel Telegram to BotFramework not working

Tags: botframework, telegram

I'm trying to add a channel to my Bot at dev.botframework.com but when I try to submit the access token of telegram, I'm getting a Runtime Error.
I tryed a new Access token and an old one from a previous bot, but it don't work.

Is that an error in my bot or on the Website / at telegram? I can use the bot with the webchat without any Problems.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reporting this. It's a temporary error and we're testing the fix for it now.

Answer (score 0):

This was already fixed per this [thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2355).